# Testing default scope in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

all.
I am having difficulties to write a test for my model with default scope. I have a user model with attribute active_status which can be changed by admin. I gave the user default scope active_status true. default_scope(:active_status => true ) In Admin page I used unscoped so that Admin can see all the users.
How to write this test?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could so something along the lines of this:

```
context "scopes" do
  describe "default_scope" do
    before do 
      create(:user, active_status: true) 
      create(:user, active_status: false)
    }

    context "with default scope" do
      subject { User.all }

      it { should have(1).user }
    end

    context "without default scope" do
       subject { User.unscoped.all }

      it { should have(2).users }
    end
  end
end
```

note: I'm using [RSpec](http://rspec.info/) and [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl).

note2: You can consider this as an anti pattern, because the default_scope is a protected method. But this is what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like all you need to do is write a test for the admin page that creates an inactive user and verifies that when the admin page loads, one result is returned...  Am I missing something?